# accessing ng-grid using ng-repeat for delete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my current table, ignore the select all button for now.[image]

After doing research and googling, most solutions that involve a deletion from the grid have individual remove buttons on each row. For design/style purposes i'm are against it. The problem arises with the delete button calling delete function within the app-controller that is outside the scope of the ng-grid

```
  div class="btn-group">
  <button class="my-btn btn-default button-row-provider-medical-services" ng-click="deleteProviderMedicalService(id,$index)">Delete</button>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="gridStyle ngGridTable" ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>
```

The button takes 2 parameters, one for id to be deleted from the database, and the other is the row to be deleted. Straight forward only if the data was displayed using ng-repeat.

My question is if it is possible to access ng-grid data using ng-repeat? Checking the jdom reveals that the rows and columns are rendered using ng-repeat, and the table itself is under the class ng-Viewport ng-scope.

Comment: Do you need to delete only rows where checkbox checked?

Comment: yep! Most solutions online involve single deletion

Comment: Are `deleteProviderMedicalService` and options for ngGrid exist in the same scope?

Comment: no the delete exists outside of the ng-grid unfortunately

Comment: Is it declared in parent scope?

Comment: both the button and grid are within the same scope of the controller

Answer (score 0):

you can get selected objects from the `selectedItems` property of ngGrid. Also, you can get id from selected object itseld and his index in data source array and pass this data into `deleteProviderMedicalService` function for each selected item.

```
var selectedItems = [];

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'myData',
  showSelectionCheckbox: true,
  selectedItems: selectedItems
};

$scope.deleteSelected = function(){
  angular.forEach(selectedItems, 
     function(svc){ $scope.deleteProviderMedicalService(svc.id, myData.ondexOf(svc)); });
};
```

Comment: thank you, my delete works, but i wanted something along like this http://plnkr.co/edit/eqZRW0oSl6ekmcxjyjCF?p=preview (i just got linked to by coworker)